# How to merge pandas table by regex on multiple columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, join

Given the following data frames join\merge df1 and df2 to result in df3 in the following manner:
df1.a join on regex matching to df2.a AND df1.b join on regex matching to df2.b

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar','zoolo','foo','foo'], 'b': ['tty','abc', 'uhg','abc','tty'], 'c':[14,72,93,33,57]})
```

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | tty | 14 |
| 1 | bar | abc | 72 |
| 2 | zoolo | uhg | 93 |
| 3 | foo | abc | 33 |
| 4 | foo | tty | 57 |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['zool(o|r)','foo|oof','[badr]+'],'b': ['uh(f|g)','[ty]+','abc|bac'], 'j': [11,32,65]})
```

|  | a | b | j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | zool(o|r) | uh(f|g) | 11 |
| 1 | foo|oof | [ty]+ | 32 |
| 2 | [badr]+ | abc|bac | 65 |

##### Result

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar','zoolo','foo'], 'b': ['tty','abc', 'uhg','tty'], 'c':[14,72,93,57],'j': [32,65,11,32]}, )
```

|  | a | b | c | j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | tty | 14 | 32 |
| 1 | bar | abc | 72 | 65 |
| 2 | zoolo | uhg | 93 | 11 |
| 4 | foo | tty | 57 | 32 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(dfRow):
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        if re.match(row["a"], dfRow["a"]) and re.match(row["b"], dfRow["b"]):
            return dfRow.append(row[["j"]])

df1.apply(func, axis=1).dropna()
```